# CSS Position only updates after changes

Tags: css, wordpress

I try to setup the position of diffrent images on a site. I use the Avada Theme to create a basic column layout (3 colums, 2 rows) and css to make more specific configurations on it. My divs, which are containing the img's have IDs I use.

```css
#note_col1_row1{
position: relative;
z-index: 1001;
top: 5%;
left: 3%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(1.3);
transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(1.3);
} 

#note_col2_row1{ 
position: relative;
z-index: 1001;
  bottom: 4%;
  left: 4%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(4deg) scale(1);
transform: rotate(4deg) scale(1);
}

#note_col1_row2{
position: relative;
z-index: 1001;
  left: 2%;
  bottom: 22%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(2deg) scale(1.2);
transform: rotate(2deg) scale(1.2);
}

#note_col3_row1{
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
top: 4%;
left: 5%;
width: 170px !important;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(1.2);
transform: rotate(-2deg) scale(1.2);
}

#note_col2_row2{
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
top: 5%;
left: 5%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg) scale(1.3);
transform: rotate(-4deg) scale(1.3);
} 

#note_col3_row2{
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
bottom: 15%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(2deg) scale(0.8);
transform: rotate(2deg) scale(0.8);
}
```

So now my problem is, if I load the page the bottom,top... positions don't apply to the divs. This only happens if I start the debug view via F12 and change a value to any other (for example "bottom: 22%;" to "bottom: 21%;").
Is there any reason why this behaves like this and any possibilty to solve the problem?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you had a link to JSFiddle/Plunkr/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting position to `absolute` rather than `relative` like this:

```
#note_col1_row1
{
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That would probably change the layout in dramatic ways.

Comment: Yes, I tried the absolute variant, but then the "top:" value doesn't make changes anymore and everything is stacked in one row : /

Comment: I don't  see how. You are specifying exact locations for the divs... Isn't that the purpose of `position: absolute` ? Absolute positioning positions the div relative to the first parent div (the closest parent div with `position:relative`) that it is in.

Comment: Try giving the parent div `position:relative;` and `float: left;` or add a new parent div and add `position:relative;` `float:left;` `width:100%`. I think it might be a problem with positioning. I would have all the divs be `position:absolute` inside a `position:relative;` parent div in your case.

Comment: Ah! Ok, figured out how to set the absolute position in a vertically way. I still used %-values but with px-values it works. Responsibility will kill me ^^